# ArcGIS Online attribute value as hyperlink in popup

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-webmap

I have two attribute values in my feature class table. One that is the Name of a Regulation (Name) and the other a link to the online explanation of the regulation (RegulationLink).   I'd like my popup to display the Regulation name (Name) but make the text value a hyperlink to the URL stored in the RegulationLink field.

Is this possible in the map viewer?

Answer (score 1):

In the popup editor, add a new 'text' field and then enter the field {Name} - then highlight it and select to insert a link. In the URL for the link, just enter in the field with the URL, in this case, {RegulationLink} - you can then check the source code to make sure that it formats correctly.

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it worked (kind of).  The text is hyperlinked but clicking on it opens another version of the map I'm working on and not the url stored in the RegulationLink field?  Should that field be text or hyperlink text type?

Comment: Wait I got it.  I was pointing to the wrong field.. Thanks so much

Comment: Alternatively, if you were wanting it to display as part of your normal fields list section you could either calculate a field on the table to the html link tag `<a href="YOUR LINK">Descriptive Text</a>` or create an expression in the pop up to output this text and add it to your fields list for your fields list section.